# updated modules via pip3 but Python 3.7 using libraries from homedir/ .local/lib/python3.1/site-packages instead

Tags: python-3.x, pip

When I used pip3 to "install --upgrade  PySimpleGUI" it got installed in the/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages directory but my python install (when run as a local user) wants to use the users ~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages directory for the module.  The modules in that path do not get updated.

My workaround to the problem was to delete all the files under  /.local/lib/

But this feels wrong.  How did PSG get installed in the .local/lib to begin with and how do I tell Python to use the /usr/local/python3.7/dist-packags exclusively

Comment: Does virtual environments play any role?